# Parallel plate capacitance to co-pplanar capacitance

Tags: capacitor, impedance, capacitance

[image: Complete setup]So in my [previous experiment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372977/using-ad5933-with-an-external-amplification-to-measure-changes-of-permittivity), I made a parallel plate capacitor by putting 2 copper plates parallel to each other (the third figure in the image). I then hooked up the AD5933 evaluation board (which is an impedance analyzer) and then I put in things in between and observed the dispersion in biological materials (fruits and veggies).

My task now is to "open" up the plates to they're co-planar. I have done that and placed an active shield at the back of the plates to direct my electric fields. However, now I see no observable change on the impedance analyzer when I bring myself or fruits/veggies close to the fields. I do "feel" the field since I sense a bit of warmth closer to the plates. I observed the oscilloscope which is hooked up to the end of the receive plate and I don't see much of an observable difference, rather I see a very small change. I must include the fact that I've tried with the active shield, passive shield and even without the shield. And they all have the same effect ie: no change of impedance.

PS...even in my parallel plate configuration, the change in the oscilloscope observed is very minimal.

My question is NOT about why I am NOT getting any change. I know the reason, I would just like to validate it before I take it up with my superiors.

I think the reason that I am NOT observing an change of impedance is because a) the impedance analyzer requires a calibration for the open-plate setup ie: the capacitance across the open plates is obviously NOT the same as the capacitance across the parallel plates. And change of capacitance = change of impedance = new calibration range needed. And b) also, co-planar capacitance is complex and has to be simulated and only then will I arrive at a value.

So would it be right to think that I first need to analytically look at the open-plates and then based on some simulations, apply the formula/value to calibration for the impedance analyzer.

Another fact is that the impedance analyzer cannot measure below 1kOhm. This value can actually be lesser; but in my case I'm using the evaluation board so its limited to 1kOhm - 1MOhm. But this of course comes in WHEN I know the capacitance of these co-planar plates.

[image: Capacitor fields]

Comment: There is no benefit from your experiment. The only success you will have is to follow my suggestion on your previous question. Period! The reasons are many as it follows the method of  any bridge meter , putting the fruit in water will match the approximate dielectric of fruit rather than air which is 1.25% of water capacitance in series making changes very insensitive when fruit is immersed

Comment: The benefit is to "observe" the dispersion. Not to observe the absolute values of permittivity. Your explanation makes sense but in my case I'm only interested in the dispersion curve NOT the absolute value. And I cannot remove air.

Comment: Of course you can and you must! You cannot measure a 3D property with a weak 1D measurement

Comment: I cannot. The air is part of my setup.

Comment: No you balance the vector impedance to null with water between parallel plates bigger than the fruit then detect the vector difference of immersed fruit to the exact same level of water ( full ) use a square glass box or mini aquarium and make the water volume only big enough to contain the similar size of fruit and extend beyond the plates to eliminate fringing

Comment: Then your setup is faulty for this test, try a waveguide at 1GHz instead

Comment: My question here is about the open-plate capacitor. I need this frequency range. I cannot change it. My intention here (as I've mentioned) is NOT to observe the actual value of permittivity. Since that requires higher precision+accuracy and an entirely different setup. My intention here is to see the dispersion curve so that I can ID active and passive materials. Just ID them, not characterize them to an accurate extent.

Comment: Well then it is like detecting a nail 1m under the ground with a magnetic dual loop and will be very insensitive with all the air. Then use a directional 1GHz transceiver pair then air will have less effect using a multiple of 1/2 wave and simply monitor RSSI or even 5GHz or a laptop and router with care on antenna paths in close range

Comment: Putting your hands apart around fruit is around 1pF and with a large air gap and fruit between maybe 1.01pf relatively speaking (hand waving argument) pun intended . Show a useful photo and reason for this experiment

Comment: I agree about the challenges/pit-falls of it. Hence as I said, its simply to ID. To see if its even possible and if so, by what margin.

Comment: Show experiment and your expected acceptance / rejection criteria then I can tell you about error margin. Otherwise you are wasting your time

Comment: Alright. Shall upload images of my results. Of parallel plate. Since thats what I've done so far.

Comment: And define ID acceptance/rejection criteria errors best way you know how

Comment: You don't describe your "active shield," but is it possible the plates are coupling though the shield and thus not responding significantly to lesser conductors?

Comment: Please include the "active shield" in your diagrams. Also if "active" means it's driven by some circuit to some potential, include a schematic of that circuit.

Comment: Added info. :) I have thought about that, but it seems like the fields are (probably) going from the tx to a guard ring placed around the rx end and the rest is on the rx late itself but its very less compared to parallel plate. I've been told that the field here would indeed be much lesser as compared to parallel plate fields.

Comment: @ThePhoton I've done so. I've tried it in all 3 conditions: active shield, passive shield and no shield.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt http://tinypic.com/r/2yl4coz/9 this is how it should be. In this case, its a cucumber vs air.

Comment: Let me reiterate, these experiments are useless and are not even close to how you should measure bio-impedance spectrum for dispersion of conductance and permittivity vs f. You have a lot of reading to find and learn how it’s done

Comment: And let me reiterate that this is not for any accuracy. Its just to see if its possible to observe dispersion wirelessly.